# When representable functions are recursive

Tags: logic

I'm trying to show the following statement: A representable function in a true, effectively axiomatizable theory is recursive.

I'm missing one step in my proof: I need to show that the relation:

$ a_0 = f(a_1,…,a_n) \Leftrightarrow T \vdash \phi(a_0,…,a_n)$

where $f$ is represented by $\phi$ is recursively enumerable. We defined a theory $T$ to be effectively axiomatizable when $\{$ Goedelnumber($\phi$)$ | \phi$ L sentence, $T \vdash \phi \}$ is recursively enumerable so I'm trying to use that but no luck so far.

[Edit: Thank you for the answer, but (this is my first logic intro course) we've only covered the enumerability definitions of recursively enumerable functions and I'm a bit out of my depth with semidecidability.]

Comment: Anyone have any help regarding the edit?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is effectively axiomatizable, the set $\{\varphi: T\vdash\varphi\}$ is recursively enumerable. Suppose $f$ is a single-variable (for simplicity) representable function, via some formula $\varphi$; I want an algorithm which determines the value of $f(n)$, for each numeral $n$.

By definition of representability, $f(n)=k$ if and only if $T\vdash \varphi(n, k)$; at the same time, since $f$ is total, we know that for each $n$ there is *some* $k$ such that $T\vdash \varphi(n, k)$ - namely, $k=f(n)$.

So let's say I want to compute $f(n)$. Basically, I'm looking for some $k$ such that $T\vdash\varphi(n, k)$. To find such a $k$, here's a reasonable idea: run programs $\Phi_e$, where $\Phi_e$ is looking for a proof of $\varphi(n, e)$ from $T$, simultaneously, and wait for one of them to halt (one must - specifically, $\Phi_{f(n)}$). Now of course this is a bit nonsense, since it involves running infinitely many programs simultaneously; is there a way we can get around this?

Comment: Nice answer, Noah; ***endorsed!***

Answer (score 0):

The standard trick for doing such a "simulatenous run of infinitely many" $\Phi_e$s is to dovetail their executions. Since one of them terminates, the whole process can stop once this happens. (Dovetailing means:

- run 2 steps of $\Phi_1$ and first step of $\Phi_2$, then
- third step of $\Phi_1$, second of $\Phi_2$ and first of $\Phi_3$, then
- fourth of $\Phi_1$, third of $\Phi_2$, second of $\Phi_3$ and first of $\Phi_4$, etc..)